# Custom Table View Cell as String

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm updating my app from Swift 2 to Swift 4 and there seems to be some lost functionality when it comes to converting a UITableViewCell to a String via:

```
String(MyTableViewCell)
```

The instance I'm attempting to use it in would be:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:String(PlayerReportCell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlayerReportCell
```

Was this just lost functionality or is there a new way of doing this?

The error that I'm getting is..

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '((PlayerReportCell).Type)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember being able to do it before, but in Swift 4.2, you can do:

```
 "\(PlayerReportCell.self)"
```

It's basically using string interpolation to interpolate the meta type object of the type.

Or, use `String(describing:)`

```
String(describing: PlayerReportCell.self)
```

Note that this relies on implementation detail and might break in a future swift version, just like your old code did. It’s better to hardcode the identifier in.

Comment: Why not hardcode the cell identifier? Relying on the output of `String(describing: PlayerReportCell.self)` to actually match the cell identifier is relying on an implementation detail.

Comment: @rmaddy I know, but I think this is a little irrelevant. OP seems to be asking about getting s type’s name as a string

Comment: Right. That's my point. It's being used as the cell identifier. Your solution could break in a future Swift update. The cell identifier won't change but the output of `String(describing: PlayerReportCell.self)` might and that will cause the app to fail.

Comment: @rmaddy but it’s been compiled, hasn’t it? An app wouldn’t crash because a new swift version came out. OP has to recompile with a newer version of Swift and find out that this crashes the app. I will add a warning anyway though.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't clear on that. It wouldn't just start failing on users' devices.